# Webpack Typescript relative dependency defined in package.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, dependencies, package.json

I recently created a React-Native app and used relative dependencies defined in a package.json in each folder to avoid `../../../` like paths.

I have to create a React (DOM) app, so I created my own webpack config and wanted to reproduce the same behaviour.

So I have :

**./app/package.json:**

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "test-service": "file:./services/Test",
        "home-screen": "file:./screens/Home"
    }
}
```

**./app/screens/Home/package.json:**

```
{
    "name": "home-screen",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {}
}
```

**./webpack.config.js:**

```
{
    //...
    resolve: {
        descriptionFiles: ['package.json'],
        alias: {
            app: path.resolve(sourcePath)
        },
        modules: [path.resolve(sourcePath), 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.js', 'jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        mainFields: ['module', 'main']
    },
    //...
}
```

**./tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    //...
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./app",
    "paths": {
        "app/*": ["./*"]
    },
    //...
}
```

**./app/App.tsx (entry point)**

```
import { Screen } from 'home-screen'
//...
```

### And webpack tells me that he cannot find the `home-screen` module !

Error log : https://pastebin.com/ai14n74h

Do you known how I can resolve this issue and use package.json dependencies as aliases ?

I already used aliases from webpack but I'm not convinced by the usage, I think node dependencies should be the best way to handle the behaviour I need.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think a better option, and one that would definitely work with the typescript compiler, would be to only define those path aliases in the paths node of tsconfig.json, and use the tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin so webpack is aware of them.
I think the TS compiler is having trouble resolving them in combination with the package.json dependencies.

Comment: The package.json dependencies works with React-Native (and ts) so I think the problem is webpack related.